# How can I get the cartesian product of a set of intervals with no overlapping?

Tags: python, cartesian-product, constraint-programming

given a dictionary with a set of intervals:

> intervals = {'561801/03/08': [[1081, 1156], [1141, 1216], [1201, 1276], [1741, 1816], [1801, 1876], [1861, 1936], [1921, 1996], [1981, 2056], [2041, 2116]], '563301/03/08': [[1170, 1250], [1230, 1310], [1770, 1850], [1830, 1910], [1890, 1970], [1950, 2030], [2010, 2090], [2070, 2150], [2130, 2210]], '688002/03/08': [[1790, 1850], [1850, 1910], [1910, 1970], [1970, 2030], [2090, 2150], [2150, 2210], [2210, 2270], [2270, 2330], [2330, 2390], [2390, 2450], [2450, 2510], [2510, 2570], [2570, 2630], [2630, 2690], [2690, 2750]], '690102/03/08': [[1900, 1960], [1960, 2020], [2020, 2080], [2080, 2140], [2200, 2260], [2260, 2320], [2320, 2380], [2380, 2440], [2440, 2500], [2500, 2560], [2560, 2620], [2620, 2680], [2680, 2740]], '559402/03/08': [[2015, 2090], [2075, 2150], [2135, 2210], [2195, 2270], [2255, 2330], [2315, 2390], [2375, 2450], [2435, 2510], [2495, 2570], [2555, 2630], [2615, 2690], [2675, 2750]], '561302/03/08': [[2310, 2390], [2370, 2450], [2430, 2510], [2490, 2570], [2550, 2630], [2610, 2690], [2670, 2750]], '572602/03/08': [[2435, 2505], [2495, 2565], [2555, 2625], [2615, 2685], [2675, 2745]], '572502/03/08': [[2560, 2640], [2620, 2700]]}

the cartesian product can be obtained using:

```
prod = itertools.product(*intervals)
```

the size of this cartesian product is 9*9*15*13*12*7*5*2 = 13,267,800

I wish to reduce it by not allowing combinations where two or more domains overlap. This combination is OK:

> [1081, 1156], [1170, 1250], [1790, 1850], [1900, 1960], [2015, 2090],
> [2310, 2390], [2435, 2505], [2560, 2640] OK

This combination is not OK

> **[1141, 1216], [1170, 1250]**, [1790, 1850], [1900, 1960], [2015, 2090],
> [2310, 2390], [2435, 2505], [2560, 2640] not OK

and any further combinations starting with:

> **[1141, 1216], [1170, 1250]**

should not be considered. This excludes 15*13*12*7*5*2 = 163,800 combinations
The purpose is to reduce significantly the size of the cartesian product, to only have intervals that do not overlap.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you present this in more digestable format. Shrink it to 2-3 sets of 2-3 intervals, and give the exact output you expect. Your `itertools.product(*intervals)` does not even touch the dict values and has, thus,  nothing to do with any intervals...

Comment: Are we talking about the product of the *endpoints* of intervals, or the product of all values within the intervals?

Comment: 9*9*15*13*12*7*5*2 = 13,267,800 <br>

Comment: @user2390182 this is as digestable as it gets. itertools works fine with dictionaries. This is a very complicated problem.

Comment: @chepner we are talking about the endpoints where any interval is inside any of the others. Thanks

Comment: @FranciscoLemos Which intervals (keys) do you consider not overlapping? When I check it's '688002/03/08' and  '690102/03/08' with sizes 15*13 = 195.

Comment: @hkank the number of combinations 195 is correct (my bad the * disappeared); the first interval of  688002/03/08, [1790, 1850], never overlaps with the intervals of 690102/03/08. However the second interval of 688002/03/08, [1850, 1910], overlaps with the first of  690102/03/08,  [1900, 1960] (1910 is between 1900 and 1960). Any combination of the cartesian having [[...], [1850, 1910] ,[1900, 1960] [...]] is to be dismissed. For this case 9*9*12*7*5*2 = 68040. The objective is to reduce the total number of combinations from the cartesian product just to those intervals that do not overlap.

Comment: @FranciscoLemos So the problem is both to check if a list of intervals has any overlaps, AND to check if there are any overlaps between any two lists of intervals?

Comment: @hanank, the problem is to check if an interval overlaps any of the others in a combination ( Pl. look at the 2 examples given). Imagine all the combinations from those vectors, what is intended are only those that have no overlapping intervals.  It is similar to sudoku constraint propagation, but instead of numbers in this case instead of numbers, it is intervals.

Comment: @FranciscoLemos Sorry, I still don't get it. Is the objective to pick exactly one interval from each interval list and only accept those combinations that don't have an overlap? If so, a (preliminary) result is that it's 12201 such combinations. (I'm prototyping this in a CP system, but not in Python right now).

Comment: You are expected to write a [mcve] - emphasis on *minimal* - and include your expected output. Just because the problem is complicated doesn't mean you can't give a smaller example of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I interpret the question as follows: pick exactly one interval from each intervals list and accept only those combinations that don't have any overlaps.

Below is a Constraint Programming model in CPMPy (https://github.com/CPMpy/cpmpy). It use the `Element` constraint to pick the selected `x[i]`'th interval from the `i`'th interval list.

The basic constraints are:

```py
~( (starts[i] >= starts[j]) & (starts[i] <= ends[j]))
~( (starts[j] >= starts[i]) & (starts[j] <= ends[i]))
```

Which ensures that the `i`'th selected interval does not overlap with the `j`'th interval (and vice versa). (Note: `~` means `not`.)

```py
from cpmpy import *
from cpmpy.solvers import *
from cpmpy_hakank import * # See http://hakank.org/cpmpy/cpmpy_hakank.py

def print_solution(a):
    """
    Print the solution.
    """
    # The selected intervals, as indices in each interval list
    xval = a[0].value()
    n = len(xval)
    print(xval)
    # The selected intervals, as intervals
    sols = [intervals[i][xval[i]] for i in range(n)]
    print(sols)
    print(flush=True)
    

#
# Note: intervals is a list of list of intervals (not a dictionary)
#
def reduce_overlaps(intervals):

    # Convert the list of intervals to a list of flattened lists
    # for use with Element below.
    intervals_flatten = []
    for interval in intervals:
        intervals_flatten.append(cpm_array(flatten_lists(interval)))
    intervals_flatten = cpm_array(intervals_flatten)
    
    # We need all values to create the domains of the selected interval 
    # values
    all_values = flatten_lists(intervals_flatten)
    max_val = max(all_values)
    min_val = min(all_values)
    
    n = len(intervals)
    lens = [len(interval) for interval in intervals]

    #
    # Decision variables
    #
    model = Model()

    # x[i] is the selected interval for the i'th interval list
    x = intvar(0,max(lens),shape=n,name="x")
    
    # Reduce the domain (the possible values) of each interval list
    # (since they have different lengths)
    for i in range(n):
        model += [x[i] < lens[i]]

    # starts[i] is the start value of the i'th selected interval
    starts = intvar(min_val,max_val,shape=n,name="starts")
    # ends[i] is the end value of the i'th selected interval    
    ends   = intvar(min_val,max_val,shape=n,name="ends")

    #
    # Main constraints:
    #  - Pick exactly one of the intervals from each intervals list
    #  - Ensure that there are no overlaps between any of selected intervals.
    #

    # get the values of the selected intervals
    for i in range(n):
        # Use Element to obtain the start and end values of the selected 
        # interval. We have to use the following construct with Element 
        # since CPMPy does not (yet) support this syntax:
        #    starts[i] = intervals[x[i],0]
        #    ends[i]   = intervals[x[i],1]
        model += [starts[i] == Element(intervals_flatten[i],x[i]*2+0), # corresponds to: starts[i] = intervals[x[i],0]
                  ends[i]   == Element(intervals_flatten[i],x[i]*2+1), # corresponds to: ends[i]   = intervals[x[i],1]
                  ]

    # Ensure that the i'th selected interval don't overlap with
    # the rest of the intervals (the j'th interval)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i+1,n):           
            # Ensure that the start value of one interval is not inside the other interval
            model += [~( (starts[i] >= starts[j]) & (starts[i] <= ends[j])),
                      ~( (starts[j] >= starts[i]) & (starts[j] <= ends[i])) ]


    # Print all solutions.
    # This method is defined in http://hakank.org/cpmpy/cpmpy_hakank.py
    # ortools_wrapper(model,[x],print_solution)
    # Collect the solutions in an array
    solutions = []
    def get_solution(a):
        xval = a[0].value()
        # print(xval)
        sol = [intervals[i][xval[i]] for i in range(n)]
        # print("sol:",sol)        
        solutions.append(sol)
    ortools_wrapper2(model,[x],get_solution)
        
    return np.array(solutions)


intervals_dict = {
    '561801/03/08': [[1081, 1156], [1141, 1216], [1201, 1276], [1741, 1816], [1801, 1876], [1861, 1936], [1921, 1996], [1981, 2056], [2041, 2116]],
    '563301/03/08': [[1170, 1250], [1230, 1310], [1770, 1850], [1830, 1910], [1890, 1970], [1950, 2030], [2010, 2090], [2070, 2150], [2130, 2210]],
    '688002/03/08': [[1790, 1850], [1850, 1910], [1910, 1970], [1970, 2030], [2090, 2150], [2150, 2210], [2210, 2270], [2270, 2330], [2330, 2390], [2390, 2450], [2450, 2510], [2510, 2570], [2570, 2630], [2630, 2690], [2690, 2750]],
    '690102/03/08': [[1900, 1960], [1960, 2020], [2020, 2080], [2080, 2140], [2200, 2260], [2260, 2320], [2320, 2380], [2380, 2440], [2440, 2500], [2500, 2560], [2560, 2620], [2620, 2680], [2680, 2740]],
    '559402/03/08': [[2015, 2090], [2075, 2150], [2135, 2210], [2195, 2270], [2255, 2330], [2315, 2390], [2375, 2450], [2435, 2510], [2495, 2570], [2555, 2630], [2615, 2690], [2675, 2750]],
    '561302/03/08': [[2310, 2390], [2370, 2450], [2430, 2510], [2490, 2570], [2550, 2630], [2610, 2690], [2670, 2750]],
    '572602/03/08': [[2435, 2505], [2495, 2565], [2555, 2625], [2615, 2685], [2675, 2745]],
    '572502/03/08': [[2560, 2640], [2620, 2700]]
    }

# Convert to a list of lists since this is needed for the output
intervals = [intervals_dict[a] for a in intervals_dict]
solutions = reduce_overlaps(intervals)
# print("Solutions:",solutions)
print("Num solutions:",len(solutions))
```

Note: The program uses my utilities package http://hakank.org/cpmpy/cpmpy_hakank.py .

This model give 12201 solutions showing the indices of the selected intervals and also the intervals. Here are some of these solutions:

```py
sol #1
[7 7 2 4 5 2 4 0]
[[1981, 2056], [2070, 2150], [1910, 1970], [2200, 2260], [2315, 2390], [2430, 2510], [2675, 2745], [2560, 2640]]


sol #2
[7 7 0 4 5 2 4 0]
[[1981, 2056], [2070, 2150], [1790, 1850], [2200, 2260], [2315, 2390], [2430, 2510], [2675, 2745], [2560, 2640]]


sol #3
[7 7 1 4 5 2 4 0]
[[1981, 2056], [2070, 2150], [1850, 1910], [2200, 2260], [2315, 2390], [2430, 2510], [2675, 2745], [2560, 2640]]

....

sol #12200
[4 8 2 5 0 1 1 1]
[[1801, 1876], [2130, 2210], [1910, 1970], [2260, 2320], [2015, 2090], [2370, 2450], [2495, 2565], [2620, 2700]]


sol #12201
[6 8 1 5 0 1 1 1]
[[1921, 1996], [2130, 2210], [1850, 1910], [2260, 2320], [2015, 2090], [2370, 2450], [2495, 2565], [2620, 2700]]

ExitStatus.OPTIMAL (3.59288788 seconds)
Nr solutions: 12201
Num conflicts: 302
NumBranches: 135035
WallTime: 3.59288788
```

**Update**

Here are two CP models:

- The CPMpy model (slightly different from the one above): http://hakank.org/cpmpy/reduce_overlapping_intervals_cp.py
- A Picat model (which I used to prototype the problem): http://hakank.org/picat/reduce_overlapping_intervals.pi

**Update 2**

There is another interpretation to the problem: Remove intervals from each interval list so that any combination of these remaining intervals lists (one interval taken from each interval list) does not overlap. And we require that at least one interval is kept from each interval list.

Stated like this, then there are (according to my Picat model, see below) 608599 different configurations.

Perhaps it's more interesting to instead work with only the optimal solutions, i.e. the configurations with the maximal number of kept intervals. Then the optimal number of kept intervals is 15 (again according to my Picat model), and there are 170 such configurations. (I'm surprised that the optimal number of kept intervals is just 15 , it's quite a small number of the possible 72 intervals).

Here are some of these optimal solutions (with 15 kept intervals):

```
interval = 1 = [[1081,1156],[1741,1816],[1801,1876],[1861,1936],[1921,1996],[1981,2056]]
interval = 2 = [[1170,1250],[1230,1310]]
interval = 3 = [[2150,2210],[2210,2270]]
interval = 4 = [[2080,2140]]
interval = 5 = [[2675,2750]]
interval = 6 = [[2310,2390]]
interval = 7 = [[2435,2505]]
interval = 8 = [[2560,2640]]


interval = 1 = [[1081,1156],[1141,1216],[1741,1816],[1801,1876]]
interval = 2 = [[1230,1310]]
interval = 3 = [[2150,2210],[2210,2270]]
interval = 4 = [[1900,1960],[1960,2020],[2020,2080],[2080,2140]]
interval = 5 = [[2435,2510]]
interval = 6 = [[2310,2390]]
interval = 7 = [[2675,2745]]
interval = 8 = [[2560,2640]]


interval = 1 = [[1081,1156],[1741,1816],[1801,1876]]
interval = 2 = [[1170,1250],[1230,1310]]
interval = 3 = [[2090,2150],[2150,2210],[2210,2270]]
interval = 4 = [[1900,1960],[1960,2020],[2020,2080]]
interval = 5 = [[2435,2510]]
interval = 6 = [[2310,2390]]
interval = 7 = [[2675,2745]]
interval = 8 = [[2560,2640]]
```

The Picat model for this approach is here: http://hakank.org/picat/reduce_overlapping_interval2.pi.